# Sony Vegas Pro 13 insane 4k export size

Tags: vegas-pro, 4k, export

So from my knowledge (and actual experience) Vegas 13 has *one* option for exporting 4k videos. My phone has a 4k camera, and recently I built a beefy computer and decided to edit some 4k footage.

The final product was exactly 2 minutes long, and (not kidding here) **exactly** 4GB. It was exported to NTFS formatted drive.

The video played fine on MPC-HC video player, and looked great! But why is the file size so huge?! Does Vegas 14 improve on this or is there a plugin for 13 to make it easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be a direct preset for 4K, but you can simply use the Mainconcept AVC module to export 4K. Simply select one of the 1080p presets, like **Internet 1080p**, then customize template to choose a custom frame size and enter your project resolution e.g. 4096 x 2304. Change average bitrate to `40,000,000`. Match the frame rate to your project frame rate, and you should be good to go.